# Loading huge text file in python

Tags: python

I need to process a large text file (4 GB). Which is having data as:

```
12 23 34
22 78 98
76 56 77
```

Where I need to read each line as do some work based on the lines. Currently I am doing as:

```
sample = 'filename.txt'

with open(sample) as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.split() 
      line = [int(i) for i in line]
      a = line[0]
      b = line[1]
      c = line[2]
      do_someprocess()
```

It is taking huge time to execute. Is there any other better way to do this in python??

Comment: What does do_someprocess() do? Are you sure that `split()` and `int()` are the functions taking the most time?

Comment: You can run python -m cProfile myscript.py so you're sure to optimize the right functions.

Answer (score 1):

If `do_someprocess()` takes a long time compared to reading the lines and you have extra CPU cores you could use the multiprocessing module.

Try using pypy if possible. For some compute intensive tasks it is dozens of times faster than cpython

If there are a lot of duplicate ints in the file, it can surprisingly be faster to use a dict mapping than `int()` as it saves the time to create new int objects.

First step is to profile as @nathancahill suggests in the comments. Then focus your efforts on the parts where the biggest gains can be made.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns you a list. And then you are trying to access the first,second and third element by

```
line = [int(i) for i in line]
  a = line[0]
  b = line[1]
  c = line[2]
```

Instead of that you can directly say `a,b,c = line.split()` then `a` will contain `line[0]`, `b` will contain `line[1]` and `c` will contain `line[2]`. This should save you some time.

```
with open(sample) as f:
    for line in f:
      a,b,c = line.split() 
      do_someprocess()
```

An example:

```
with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c = line.split()
        print a,b,c
```

.txt file

```
12 34 45
78 67 45
```

Output:

```
12 34 45
78 67 45
```

EDIT :
I thought of elaborating on it.I have used `timeit()` module to compare the time taken by the code to run. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here.The following is the OP way of writing the code.

```
v = """ with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.split() 
      line = [int(i) for i in line]
      a = line[0]
      b = line[1]
      c = line[2]"""
import timeit
print timeit.timeit(stmt=v, number=100000)
```

Output:

```
8.94879606286   ## seconds to complete 100000 times.
```

The following is my way of writing the code.

```
s = """ with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
            for line in f:
                a,b,c = [int(s) for s in line.split()]"""

import timeit
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
```

Outputs :

```
7.60287380216 ## seconds to complete same number of times.
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if `line` has more than 3 elements. Better to say `a, b, c = line.split()[:3]`

Comment: OP just mentioned only three data values in his/her example.

Comment: Your code is skipping the step of converting the values to int

Comment: @gnibbler You were right. I have edited my code now.